# No TCS34725 found ... check your connections

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

My TCS34725 is plugged in on an ESP8266. when the ESP boots, i got this message because it can't detect the TCS.

here is the full code in the ESP if it can help !

Connections and Wires are fine as they were working already, but now, be it with a new sensor, ESP or wires it doesn't recognize it (i have tested with all combinaisons i could with 4 ESP and 5 sensors)

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"


const char* ssid = "Karting";
const char* password = "";
char i = 0;
char color; 
WiFiUDP Udp;
unsigned int localUdpPort = 4444;  // local port to listen on
char incomingPacket[255];  // buffer for incoming packets
//char  replyPacket[] = "1";  // a reply string to send back

Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS, TCS34725_GAIN_1X);


void setup()
{
  pinMode(14,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
  WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASS");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" connected");

  if (tcs.begin()) {
   Serial.println("Found sensor");
  } else {
   Serial.println("No TCS34725 found ... check your connections");
   while(1);
  }

  Udp.begin(4444);
    Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)

  Serial.printf("Now listening at IP %s, UDP port %d\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), localUdpPort);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);

}


void loop()
{

  uint16_t r, g, b, c, colorTemp, lux;
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();

  tcs.getRawData(&r, &g, &b, &c);
  colorTemp = tcs.calculateColorTemperature(r, g, b);
  lux = tcs.calculateLux(r, g, b);

  Serial.print("Color Temp: "); Serial.print(colorTemp, DEC); Serial.print(" K - ");
  Serial.print("Lux: "); Serial.print(lux); Serial.print(" - ");
  Serial.print("R: "); Serial.print(r, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("G: "); Serial.print(g, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("B: "); Serial.print(b, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("C: "); Serial.print(c, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(" ");

  if ((r > g) && (r > b) && (colorTemp > 7300) && (colorTemp < 7600))
  {
    i = 1;
    color = 'R';
    digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  }

  if ((g > r) && (g > b) && (colorTemp > 7300) && (colorTemp < 7600))
  {
    i = 1;
    color = 'G';
    digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  }

  if ((b > r) && (b > g) && (colorTemp > 9500) && (colorTemp < 9800))
  {
    i = 1;
    color = 'B';
    digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  }
  else {
    if ((lux >2000 ) && (lux <2500) && (colorTemp > 5800) && (colorTemp < 6400))
    {
    i = 1;
    color = 'W';
    digitalWrite(14,LOW);
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(color);
    Udp.endPacket();
    Serial.println("pupupupute");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());
    }

  if (packetSize!=0)
  {
    digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
    Serial.printf("Received %d bytes from %s, port %d\n", packetSize, Udp.remoteIP().toString().c_str(), Udp.remotePort());
    int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
    if (len > 0)
    {
      Wire.beginTransmission(8); // transmit to device #8
      Wire.write("x is ");        // sends five bytes
      Wire.write(incomingPacket);              // sends one byte
      Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
      Serial.printf("UDP packet contents: %s\n", incomingPacket);
      incomingPacket[len] = 0;
    }

  }

}
}
void requestEvent() {
  if ( i = 1 )
  {
    Wire.beginTransmission(8);
    Wire.write( color );
    Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your hardware and code were tested and working earlier, this is obviously due to a change in the compiler.

Go to Arduino IDE boards manager, and check for which version of Esp8266 core you are using. Try switching to older versions, one of them will definitely work for you.

Comment: I try with the older version and it doesn't work, if you have another idea don't miss me ^^

Comment: Ok i resolve it, line scl / sda inversed (wrong  welding)